# Show there do not exist functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x+y) = g(x) - y$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

As the title says, the problem is:

Show there do not exist functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x+y) = g(x) - y$ for all $x$ and $y$.

I think the exercise is wrong/has a typo, since it seems that $f(x) = 3 - x = g(x)$ works, right?

This exercise is number 17 in the functions section in Spivak's Calculus 1st Edition, and I have not found any erratas online, so I want to confirm that I am correct and this exercise indeed has a mistake/typo.

Comment: Well the left side isn't a function of $x+y$ so this example doesn't work

Comment: I think it works because $f(x+y) = 3 - (x+y)$  based on my example

Comment: Ah I misread this, my bad. Yes indeed your example does work

Comment: Well, by the third edition he had modified/eliminated to problem.... I'm actually surprised he would have made such an error.  I wonder if there was some other condition.  Could it have been $f(x+y) = |g(x) - y|$.  I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Maybe he meant "distinct functions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting $y=0$ we get $f(x)=g(x)$, so we can rewrite the equation as
$$f(x+y)=f(x)-y.$$
Next, setting $x=0$, we get $f(y)=f(0)-y$. If we let $c=f(0)$, then we have $f(y)=c-y$; so $f(x)=g(x)=c-x$ for all $x$, where $c$ is a constant. Since
$$c-(x+y)=(c-x)-y,$$
the general solution of the functional equation is
$$f(x)=g(x)=c-x$$
where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... Doesn't seem to be an issue that I can see.

$f(x) = f(x+0) = f(0+x)$ so if this is true we must have $f(x) = g(x) -0 = g(0) - x$ for all $x$.

And as $g(0)$ is fixed we must have $f(x)= g(x) = c - x$ where $c = f(0) = g(0)$.

Now for any $w=x+y$ there are, of course an infinite number of $x,y$ choices where $x+y = w$.

But so long as $a+b = w$ then $f(a+b) = g(a) -b = c-a - b = c-(a+b) = c-w$ and there simply is no conflict.